# SQL server: Top 5 Advertisers & All Other for each subgroup

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I have a table that has Partner Parent --> Partner --> Advertiser, I'm looking to pull Top 5 Advertisers for each Partner with an "All Other" group summing the rest of the sales together.

My code so far:

```
select [Partner Parent], [Partner], [Advertiser], [Revenue]
from (
    select [Partner Parent], [Partner], [Advertiser], [Revenue] = ISNULL(SUM([Revenue]), 0),
rn = row_number() over (partition by [Partner] order by ISNULL(SUM([Revenue]), 0) DESC)
from [table]
group by [Partner Parent], [Partner], [Advertiser]
) a where a.rn <= 5
```

That gets me my Top 5... How do I get the "All Other" within this code?

I've also tried to re-use code I saw here but this just takes the top 5 and "All Other" all up and not at the Partner level

```
 select coalesce(d.[Advertiser], 'All Other') as [Advertiser]
   ,sum(t.[Revenue]) as [Revenue]
from   [table] t
left outer join
   (
   select top 5 [Advertiser] 
   from [table] 
   group by [Partner Parent], [Advertiser] 
   order by sum([Revenue]) desc
   ) d
          on d.[Advertiser] = t.[Advertiser]
group by  [Partner Parent], case when d.[Advertiser] is null then 1 else 0 end 
   ,coalesce(d.[Advertiser], 'All Other') 
order by case when d.[Advertiser] is null then 1 else 0 end
   ,sum(t.[Revenue]) desc
```

Suggestions? 
Thanks

EDIT:

Sample Data:

```
| Partner Parent |        Partner |               Advertiser | Revenue |
|----------------|----------------|--------------------------|---------|
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |               Air Canada |     500 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |         Mazda Motor Corp |     400 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |              Ford Motors |     300 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |        Land Rover Motors |     200 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |     Kaspersky Anti-Virus |     100 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |                   Jaguar |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada | Delta Hotels and Resorts |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |          Toronto Tourism |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |          Yum Restaurants |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |        Universal Studios |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |                 Manulife |     500 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |                     CIBC |     400 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |               Pfizer Inc |     300 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |            TD Bank Group |     200 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |         General Electric |     100 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |              Tim Hortons |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |       Universal Pictures |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |                    Dyson |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |            Suncor Energy |      10 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |        Entertainment One |      10 |
```

Output should be:

```
| Partner Parent |        Partner |           Advertiser | Revenue |
|----------------|----------------|----------------------|---------|
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |           Air Canada |     500 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |     Mazda Motor Corp |     400 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |          Ford Motors |     300 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |    Land Rover Motors |     200 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada | Kaspersky Anti-Virus |     100 |
|        Partner | Partner-Canada |            All Other |      50 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |             Manulife |     500 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |                 CIBC |     400 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |           Pfizer Inc |     300 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |        TD Bank Group |     200 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |     General Electric |     100 |
|        Partner | Partner-Norway |            All Other |      50 |
```

etc.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result. SQL Fiddle would be nice.

Comment: does that help? sorry... still new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `ROW_NUMBER` and `SUM()` to get the `All Others`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27f37/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Partner Parent], Partner ORDER BY Revenue DESC)
    FROM [table]
)
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT
        [Partner Parent],
        Partner,
        Advertiser,
        Revenue
    FROM Cte
    WHERE RN <= 5

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        [Partner Parent],
        Partner,
        Advertiser = 'All Other',
        Revenue = SUM(Revenue)
    FROM Cte
    WHERE RN > 5
    GROUP BY 
    [Partner Parent], Partner
)t
ORDER BY 
    [Partner Parent],
    Partner,
    CASE 
        WHEN Advertiser = 'All Other' THEN NULL
        ELSE Revenue
    END DESC
```

Comment: I suspect there will be an issue if any partner has less than 5 advertisers, does the OP want an `'All Other'` row regardless?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I don't need the 'All Other' if advertisers is less than 5